# Prevent qDebug() from writing to std output

Tags: c++, qt, qdebug

I am using `qDebug()`, `qInfo()` and so on in combination of `qInstallMessageHandler` to write my `logfiles`. I also get an output on my batch screen, when executing my application.

I only found `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT`, but I want to toggle this configuration while run-time. Is there a way to prevent Qt from writing to std output?

Comment: Doesn't `qInstallMessageHandler` help to filter all debug messages out?

Comment: sadly no, you only get access to the messages, but cannot prevent from beeing written to std output.

Comment: Why not? Handle `case QtDebugMsg:` and just break without printing anything out.

Comment: I only print it out into a file, not into std output. This is my code:

static void simpleLoggerMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
  QTextStream(QcgSimpleLogger::theSimpleLogger->getLogFile()) << msg) << endl;
}

Comment: This is not a good idea at all. The recreation of `QTextStream` performs poorly.

Comment: In my testing,  the default message handler never writes to standard out - it always goes to the standard *error* stream, as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sadly no, you only get access to the messages, but cannot prevent from beeing written to std output.

That's false in Qt 5 at the very least. The message printing code [looks as follows](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qlogging.cpp.html#_ZL16qt_message_print9QtMsgTypeRK18QMessageLogContextRK7QString): you can clearly see that only the message handler is being used:

```
if (grabMessageHandler()) {
    // prefer new message handler over the old one
    if (msgHandler.load() == qDefaultMsgHandler
            || messageHandler.load() != qDefaultMessageHandler) {
        (*messageHandler.load())(msgType, context, message);
    } else {
        (*msgHandler.load())(msgType, message.toLocal8Bit().constData());
    }
    ungrabMessageHandler();
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message.toLocal8Bit().constData());
}
```

As you can see, the `fprintf(stderr, ...)` is a fallback only if recursion is detected from within the `messageHandler` itself.

Thus, all you need to prevent any debug output is to implement and set your own `messageHandler`.

To completely turn off all the debug output in Qt, the following works:

```
#include <QtCore>
int main() {
  qDebug() << "I'm not quiet at all yet";
  qInstallMessageHandler(+[](QtMsgType, const QMessageLogContext &, const QString &){});
  qDebug() << "I'm very, very quiet";
}
```

In any case, a sensible implementation of an application-wide file logger might look as follows - it doesn't recreate the `QTextStream` unnecessarily; it uses `QString::toUtf8()` instead, and explicitly writes line endings.

```
#include <QtCore>

class Logger {
   static struct Data {
      Logger *instance;
      QtMessageHandler chainedHandler;
   } d;
   bool m_isOpen;
   QFile m_logFile;
   QtMessageHandler m_oldHandler = {};
   static void handler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg) {
      if (d.instance)
         d.instance->log(msg);
      if (d.chainedHandler)
         d.chainedHandler(type, context, msg);
   }
public:
   enum ChainMode { DontChain, Chain };
   Logger() {
      Q_ASSERT(!instance());
      m_logFile.setFileName("myLog.txt");
      m_isOpen = m_logFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text);
      d.instance = this;
   }
   ~Logger() { uninstallHandler(); }
   bool isOpen() const { return m_isOpen; }
   void installHandler(ChainMode mode) {
      Q_ASSERT(!m_oldHandler);
      m_oldHandler = qInstallMessageHandler(handler);
      if (mode == Chain)
         d.chainedHandler = m_oldHandler;
   }
   void uninstallHandler() {
      if (m_oldHandler) {
         m_oldHandler = nullptr;
         d.chainedHandler = nullptr;
         qInstallMessageHandler(m_oldHandler);
      }
   }
   /// This method is *not* thread-safe. Use with a thread-safe wrapper such as `qDebug`.
   void log(const QString & msg) {
      if (isOpen()) {
         m_logFile.write(msg.toUtf8());
         m_logFile.write("\n", 1);
      }
   }
   /// Closes the log file early - this is mostly used for testing.
   void endLog() {
      uninstallHandler();
      m_logFile.close();
   }
   static Logger *instance() { return d.instance; }
};

Logger::Data Logger::d;

template <typename T> QByteArray streamOutputFor(const T &data) {
   QBuffer buf;
   buf.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text);
   QTextStream s(&buf);
   s << data << endl;
   buf.close();
   return buf.data();
}

QByteArray readEnd(const QString &fileName, int count) {
   QFile file(fileName);
   if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text) && file.size() >= count) {
      file.seek(file.size() - count);
      return file.readAll();
   }
   return {};
}

void test() {
   auto const entry = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString().toUtf8();
   Q_ASSERT(Logger::instance()->isOpen());
   qDebug() << entry.data();
   Logger::instance()->endLog();

   auto reference = streamOutputFor(entry.data());
   auto readback = readEnd("myLog.txt", reference.size());
   Q_ASSERT(!reference.isEmpty());
   Q_ASSERT(readback == reference);
}

int main() {
   Logger logger;
   logger.installHandler(Logger::DontChain);
   qDebug() << "Something or else";
   test();
}
```